# Get inventory source details in magento 2 observer

Tags: magento2, msi, multi-source-inventory

I'm trying to get the inventory stock details for an order in observer using the event sales_order_shipment_save_after. I cannot find the inventory data.

Only getting order data.

Anyone help me.

Comment: Which concrete data do you want?

Comment: @RaulSanchez I need to get data, similar to this
'inventories' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'source' => 'T14',
            'quantity' => 236.0,
          ),

Answer (score 0):

Try This

sales_order_save_after observer is not getting order entity id

**1.Event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="magento_orderevent_create" instance="Magento\OrderEvent\Observer\OrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**2.OrderObserver.php**

```
  <?php

namespace Magento\OrderEvent\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    )
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;

    }


    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
echo($orderId);exit();
        $customer = $order->getCustomerId();

        $url = "http://captain-staging.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/order/SaveSourceData?order_id=" . $orderId. "&customer_id=" . $customer;
        echo($url);
       // print_r("customer".$customer);
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://captain-staging.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/order/SaveSourceData?order_id=" . $orderId . "&customer_id=" . $customer,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Postman-Token: de7fe4a4-f86d-4c70-ae8a-1ba1d365b005",
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            $error= "cURL Error #:" . $err;
            echo $error;
            exit();
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException(__($error));
        } else {
            print_r($response) ;
            exit();
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException(__("Order is Successfully Saved!"));
        }
    }
}
```

Re: sales_order_save_after observer is not getting order entity id

**3.Try with EntityId:**

```
/**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var OrderInterface $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getEntityId();
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($orderId);exit;
    }




**Use $order variable as OrderInterface Object.**

                       
                         Hope it helps!
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you check my observer code. I need to get source inventory data for an order.

Comment: Pls check
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order->getId());
         $orderId = $order->getEntityId();

        $sourceItems = $this->sourceItemsBySku->execute($orderId);
        $logger->info('OrderID : ' . $orderId);
        foreach ($sourceItems as $sourceItem) {
            $sourceCode = $sourceItem->getSourceCode();
            $quantity = $sourceItem->getQuantity();
            $logger->info('Source code is : ' . $sourceCode . 'Qty is ' . $quantity);
   
        }